# Is VPN necessary for networking turtlebot?

Tags: ros, wifi, turtlebot, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,

I was testing my system for installing the turtlebot setup. I was wondering if VPN is anecessary step in the networking setup? Can the two pc's communicate only via wifi ? I did not understand the concept of VPN completely.. (Lack of detailed VPN etup instructions on the turtlebot tutorial page I guess)

Next, I want to know how does one map a large area say corridors and large multiple rooms at the same time. The wifi router cannot have such large range to continue networking between the two pc's.

How to map large areas in such situation with turtlebot pc and workstation pc?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45783/is-vpn-necessary-for-networking-turtlebot?/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2012-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

VPN is only a secure way to communicate. You can run ROS over normal Wifi without problems.

The distance problem is solved by only processing data on the robot. If that isn't powerful enough, record a logfile and process that on the workstation later.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2012-10-13**:
thanks a lot, can you please tell me how to record the log file?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-10-14**:
Use the rosbag command. See: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#record